# Model Loading issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection

If I load 5 models in a controller, will the **connection to database** will be established for all the models separately ?

Because it is creating problem of server hanging, due to opening multiple ports for the database connection for each model.

If there is any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the reason?

Comment: Have you tried running your queries in a mysql client prior to trying them in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

No, codeigniter should establish a new database connection for every model you load. How did you draw the conclusion codeigniter is opening multiple ports? That shouldn't be possible

Answer (score 0):

No, CodeIgniter is using the singleton pattern, which means that you can only make one instance of each model/library (or one database connection at a time).

The problem is probably within your database queries - they might be slowing the responses. Are you using a persistant connection in the database config?

There's a lot of questions, but not much code from you, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that the problem is that? I never had any loading that amount of models, also because CI works as kinda singleton, so the object is always one, and also classes aren't re-loaded/re-instantiated if one instance already exists.

If you have probelms with your database, try setting pconnect (persistent connection) to FALSE in `config/database.php`. You might also want to turn caching ON, it might help.

```
$db['test']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
```